# How to groupBy few columns from a dataset while keeping full column selection?

Tags: apache-spark

I want to groupBy a dataset using `groupByAttributes` List, i do it like so :

```
  Dataset<Row> groupedRows = initDataset.select(initDataset.col("*")).groupBy(groupByAttributes.toArray(new Column[groupByAttributes .size()])).agg(count("*"));
```

How to return `groupedRows` with all columns of `initDataset` ?

PS : joins are not of a great help.

Comment: Use window functions if you want all the columns apart from groupByAttributes and don't want to use joins

Comment: no i want all columns including groupByAttributes . Could you elaborate your solution along with other ones such as joins in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In scala it would be like:

`val groupedRows = initDataset.withColumn("count", count().over(Window.partitionBy(groupByAttributes: _*)))`

Should be more or less similar in java.

Comment: you mean partitionBy not groupBy ? there's no groupBy in Window.

Comment: Sorry, Yep, I meant partitionBy.